# JS function that runs only on base url

Tags: javascript, function, url, location

I'm developing a site that is heavily reliant on javascript for browser history manipulation and only uses one actual page file. I want the script to run a function whenever the user hits the base url of the site, but I'm not sure what method is appropriate. Figured I could make a quick comparison of the current window location, but what if the user types in www instead of http://, or none of them. Something tells me this should be really easy.

```
if (window.location.href == 'http://mysite.com') {
    console.log('you hit the base url, yay');
    myFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by base url, you mean there is no path component or hash fragment, you can check for this as follows:

```
if (window.location.pathname==='/' && window.location.hash==="") {
    console.log('you hit the base url, yay');
    myFunction();
}
```

Comment: @ironchefpyhon this is exactly what I'm looking for, however I can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Sure, just `console.log(window.location.pathname)` at the "base url", and at other URLs, and you will know what to test for.  I went to google.com, and entered `console.log(window.location.pathname === '/')` in the chrome developer console, and I got `true`.

Comment: I think I tried to add an earlier version of your example, by including your current edit I managed to get it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to isolate the path part of the URL.

```
function isHomePage() {
    return window.location.pathname === '/' || window.location.pathname === '';
}
```

That should cover your bases, even if the URL is something like

```
https://www2.example.com:443/#hash
```

Comment: Nice function, but since I'm not reusing it I'll simply add a conditional statement instead. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Staffan I would recommend wrapping it in a function anyway so the next person to read the code doesn't have to pause and try to figure out what your intention is.

Answer (score 2):

[`window.location.href` always includes the protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Properties), so there's no issue if the user omits that when typing in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript can access the current URL in parts. For this URL:

http://mysite.com/example/index.html

```
window.location.protocol = "http"
window.location.host = "mysite.com"
window.location.pathname = "example/index.html"
```

Make it sure to use the host property

```
if (window.location.host === 'mysite.com') {
    console.log('you hit the base url, yay');
    myFunction();
}
```